# Python　URLのリダイレクト先のURLを取得する。

Tags: python, python3, http

このURLをブラウザで入力すると
http://wikipedia.simpleapi.net/ja/48503/
このページへリダイレクトします。
[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/コロッケ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1)

このような場合に、リダイレクト前のURLを引数にしてリダイレクト先のURLを取得する
方法はないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

requestsモジュールを使用してできました。

```
import requests
print(requests.get("http://wikipedia.simpleapi.net/ja/48503/").url)

> https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1
```

requestsではHTTP 301を自動的に解消するためこの方法が使えます。

Comment: ちなみに、requestsは別途インストールが必要なので、`pip install requests`などでインストールしてください。

Comment: 取得できました。ありがとうございます。